# Lyrics download api request [JAVA]

Tags: java, request

like in topic I need to write request which will use lyricwiki for downloading lyrics to my song in MP3 player. Below is the link which I should use.

http://api.wikia.com/wiki/LyricWiki_API/REST

Any tips would be great! The best would be example how to write simple request?
I have no idea how I should start. Any examples? How code using API looks like?

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer, and more likely to receive a good answer, if you included your attempt at using the API and a description of what's not working for you.

Comment: ok i fixed my question. I'm totally newbie in using API.

Comment: You just have to get to know the API you are going to use, since you will be using its functions and interfaces in order to be able to interact with that API. Its just like Java code, but with specific functions previously designed by LyricWiki in this case

Comment: Yeah but how Can I connect with this API?

Comment: I would make a Java client which would connect to a custom server, made by yourself, that forwards the request onto the LyricWiki REST web service, which in the end is a GET call

Comment: It is a HTTP Request, which you will have to check for which functionality you want, and in the end capture the answer. Check out the following link and see if it can help you: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Comment: Oh Thanks for this example I will try to figure it now:)

Comment: If you want to see any answer without coding, try the Firefox Addon RESTClient. It is a valuable tool for this kind of requests, at least for me. Just make sure you use the GET method and a link, for example http://lyrics.wikia.com/api.php?func=getArtist&artist=Linkin_Park and then you can see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty simplistic example.  It probably won't even compile without adding at least some error handling, and there's a lot I'd do to clean it up if I were going to use it, but it should give you a starting point.

```
encodeField(String in)
{
    // usually, this would be
    //  return java.net.URLEncoder.encode(in, "UTF-8");
    // but this site *appears* to use a non-standard mapping
    return java.net.URLEncoder.encode(in.replace(' ', '_'), "UTF-8");
}

getLyricsText(String artist, String song)
{
    // construct the REST query URL
    String query = "http://lyrics.wikia.com/api.php?func=getSong&artist="
                 + encodeField(artist)
                 + "&song="
                 + encodeField(song)
                 + "&fmt=text";
    // open the URL and get a stream to read from
    java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(query);
    java.io.InputStream is = url.openStream();
    // get the text from the stream as lines
    java.io.BufferedReader reader = new java.io.BufferedReader(is);
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    String s;
    while ( (s = reader.readLine()) != null )
        buf.append(s).append('\n');
    // return the lines
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Comment: It does't return complete lyrics.